# The expression " " cannot be expanded

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I've this error:
"The expression " " cannot be expanded" error 500.50 on IIS.

```
 <rule name="Imported Rule 29">
                <match url="^myhabbo/store/purchase_confirm$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="./habblet/myhabbo_store_purchase_confirm.php?type={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 30">
                <match url="^myhabbo/store/purchase_(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="./habblet/myhabbo_store_purchase.php?type={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 31">
                <match url="^myhabbo/startSession/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="./habblet/myhabbo_homes.php?id={R:1}&amp;type=startSession" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 32">
                <match url="^myhabbo/cancel/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="./habblet/myhabbo_homes.php?id={R:1}&amp;type=cancel" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 33">
                <match url="^myhabbo/save$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="./habblet/myhabbo_homes.php?id={R:1}&amp;type=save" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 34">
                <match url="^myhabbo/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="./habblet/myhabbo_{R:1}_{R:2}_{R:3}.php" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 35">
                <match url="^myhabbo/(.*)/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="./habblet/myhabbo_{R:1}_{R:2}.php" />
            </rule>
```

These are expressions that cause problems .. how can I fix?